# Why am I getting garbage values?

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, while-loop, initialization

I'm trying to make some basic number incrementation but I'm getting some weird garbage values. (this works in C# but not in C). Could someone tell me why this is not working?

```
while (1)
{
      int command = 0;

      printf ("Action: ");
      scanf ("%d", &command);


      int countX, countY, countZ = 0;
      if (command == 1)
    {
      countX++;
    }
      if (command == 2)
    {
      countY++;
    }
      if (command == 3)
    {
      countZ++;
    }
      if (command == 0)
    {
      printf ("x: %d, y: %d, z: %d", countX, countY, countZ);
    }

}
```

Comment: How many variables do you think are being initialised? Correct answer is: 1. countX, countY are not initialised.

Comment: You should explore how to turn warnings on in your compiler. In my setup this would never compile (intentionally).

Comment: [Warnings are your friend](https://godbolt.org/z/E4veva)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
int countX, countY, countZ = 0;
```

Only initializes `countZ` and leaves `countX` and `countY` **uninitialized**.  You want:

```
int countX = 0, countY = 0, countZ = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `command` is equal to `0` then you are trying to output uninitialized variables `countX` and `countY` that have indeterminate values.

You should initialize them in their declarations like

```
int countX = 0, countY = 0, countZ = 0;
```

And these statements

```
countX++;
```

and

```
countY++;
```

also have undefined behavior by the same reason because the variables were not initialized.

Pay attention to that instead of if statements you could use the switch statement.

For example

```
switch ( command )
{
case 1:
    countX++;
    break;

case 2:
    countY++;
    break;

case 3:
    countZ++;
    break;
}

printf ("x: %d, y: %d, z: %d\n", countX, countY, countZ);
```

Or you could also introduce an enumeartion the following way

```
enum { X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3 }; 
switch ( command )
{
case X:
    countX++;
    break;

case Y:
    countY++;
    break;

case Z:
    countZ++;
    break;
}

printf ("x: %d, y: %d, z: %d\n", countX, countY, countZ);
```

Or the following way

```
while ( 1 )
{
    enum { X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3 }; 
    int countX = 0, countY = 0, countZ = 0;
    int exit_loop = 0;

    int command = 0;

    printf ( "Action: " );
    scanf ( "%d", &command );

    switch ( command )
    {
    case X:
        countX++;
        break;
    
    case Y:
        countY++;
        break;
    
    case Z:
        countZ++;
        break;

    default:
        exit_loop = 1;
        break; 
    }
    
    if ( exit_loop )
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("x: %d, y: %d, z: %d\n", countX, countY, countZ);
    }
}
```